# Need some help: _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file

Tags: python

I need some help with Tkinter.
Even though my image file and code are in the same folder, I get the "_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file" error. 
I've already gone through some of the other similar stack overflow questions without success; without using PIL, how can I resolve this issue?
Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = 600, width = 1000)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg = "purple")
frame.place(relx = 0.1, relwidth = 0.8, relheight = 1)

background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'usMap.png')
background_label = tk.Label(root, image = background_image)
background_label.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the image is really png? To change formats, you have to use a converter and not just change its name.